# How to query with null value in Tuple Criteria MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, null, tuples, criteria

MYSQL query:

```
select * from CLASS where (CLASS_ID, CLASS_NAME) = (1, "FIRST");
```

Similarly i need for a tuple which contains null value like:

```
select * from CLASS where (CLASS_ID, CLASS_NAME) = (1, null);
```

But above query with null value doesn't work in mysql.

Can anyone help me with constructing query?

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check for `NULL` values using the comparison operator. Your only option is to use `IS NULL`.

So you can use something like this:

```
(CLASS_ID, CLASS_NAME) = (1, "FIRST") OR (CLASS_ID = 1 AND CLASS_NAME IS NULL)
```